# Plotting two data frames (x and y) that do not have the same dimensionality?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, svm

I have recently built an SVR model on the diamonds dataset to predict the price of a diamond, based on some specific features. I was trying to plot the test features of my model against the predicted price. Below is an explanation of the variables used in the code.

X_test - I carried out a train/test split and these are the features used to test the model on. Size 10782,7 (8 total features).

y_pred - After running the model, this will be the predicted price for each row of features in the dataset. Size 10782.

Below is the code for how these come into play

```
diamonds_features = ['carat', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'color', 'cut', 'clarity']

X = df.loc[:, diamonds_features].values
y = df.iloc[:, 6:7].values

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y.ravel(), test_size=0.20)

regressor = SVR(kernel='rbf', C=50, gamma = 10)
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)

#produce test predictions
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
```

Below is the code for plotting the outcome of the model.

```
colorGroup = ['b','g','r','c','m','y','k','w']
plt.figure(1)
for i in range(len(X_test)):
  col = colorGroup[i % 8]
  for j in range(8):
      plt.scatter(X_test[i:i+1, j:j+1], y_pred[i:i+1], color=col)
```

To go around the fact that X_test and y_pred are of different sizes, I wanted to do the following:

For each individual value in y_pred (since it is a 1d array, it will be every value),
Take every value in one row of X_test and plot it against the y_pred value. Moreover, use mod to ensure that every feature is coloured accordingly (e.g. when I am plotting carat, it will be a consistent colour throughout the plot).

The issue I get with this code is that I get the following:
"ValueError: x and y must be the same size"

If anyone could point out where I am going wrong with this, I would be grateful.

Here is the Traceback I am receiving:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\mypackage\SVM Model.py", line 72, in 
plt.scatter(X_test[i:i+1, j:j+1], y_pred[i:i+1], color=colorGroup[i%8])

File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2890, in scatter
__ret = gca().scatter(

File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib_*init*_.py", line 1438, in inner
return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\deprecation.py", line 411, in wrapper
return func(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_axes.py", line 4441, in scatter
raise ValueError("x and y must be the same size")

ValueError: x and y must be the same size

**Edit: updated the question with the Traceback**

Comment: Show a stack trace.

Comment: do you want to plot 8 different lines. all has the same y but different x, such that every x is the `X_test` column?

Comment: @MadPhysicist will do. 

Edit: updated the question with the Traceback

Comment: @LiorCohen That is correct, with the exception that I would like to plot points rather than lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comment I believe this is what you want.

As an example, I used 20 points with 3 features.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X_test = np.random.rand(20, 3)
y_pred = np.random.rand(20)
N = y_pred.size

colorGroup = ['b','g','r','c','m','y','k','w']
plt.figure(1)

for i in range(N):
    col = colorGroup[i % N]
    plt.scatter(X_test[:, i], y_pred, color=col)
```

[image]